# Ajax Post to PHP returning empty array

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I need to pass a json object from JS to PHP, and it will pass, but the result is an empty array.

Ajax request in 'adopt.php':

```
var info = JSON.stringify(filteredArray);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {'info': info},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

ajax.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['info'])){
    $_SESSION['array'] = $_POST['info'];
}
```

back in adopt.php, later:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['array'])){
    $arr = $_SESSION['array'];
    echo "console.log('information: ' + $arr);";
}
```

in both of the console.logs, it returns an empty object. Does anybody know what could be causing this? (i've tried just passing the json without stringifying it, but it throws a jquery error whenever i do this.)

Comment: did you put session_start() on top of the all pages ?

Comment: 1) `ajax.php` does not have any response body so `data` will always be empty. 2) You'd need to reload `adopt.php` in order for it to pick up any changes in `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the response data from PHP, you need to echo your data to return it to the browser.

In your ajax.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['info'])) {
    $_SESSION['array'] = $_POST['info'];
    echo json_encode(['result' => $_SESSION['array']]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's returning the object back now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code i think you miss return ajax response

**adopt.php**

```
<script>
var info = JSON.stringify(filteredArray);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {info: info},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['info'])) {
    $_SESSION['array'] = $_POST['info'];
    echo json_encode(["result" => "success"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax.php is not returning any data.To get data at the time of success you need to echo the data you want to display on success of your ajax.